# change detection using Behavior Subject with subscribe in Component Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am stuck on setting up change detection within the service layer for multiple components. Below I will just show one component to illustrate the subscribe on the behavior subject. I am not getting any errors, just no data is displaying. The http request is valid. I had this working with just two way data binding but I need the ability to update multiple components throughout the project. I thought that behavior subject might be the best choice but I could be wrong here. I really don't know/understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advice for any help.

The issue is within the getProjects() function. With the subscribe to the get request the result or error is never called before the view displays.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  private projectsUrl: string = Globals.url + '/projects';

  private getProjectsSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  getProjectsChange = this.getProjectsSource.asObservable();

  private errorSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  errorChange = this.errorSource.asObservable;

  private projects: Project[] = [];


  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getProjects() {
    if (this.projects != null) {
      this.getProjectsSource.next(this.projects);
    }
    else {

      this.http.get(this.projectsUrl, Globals.getTokenHeaders())
        .map(function (res) {
          let data = res.json();

          if (data) {
            for (let project of data.projects) {
              this.projects.push(Project.create(project));
            }
            return this.projects;
          }
        })
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'))
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.projects = result;
            this.getProjectsSource.next(this.projects);
          },
          error => {
            this.errorSource.next(true);
          });
    }
  }
}
```

This is the component which subscribes to the behavior subject setup in the service. I call the getProjects() method of the service within the constructor to trigger a change on component construction. I subscribe to it within the ngOnIt function.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html'
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  projects: Project[] = [];
  projectsFlag: boolean = false;


  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {
    this.projectService.getProjects();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.getProjectsChange.subscribe(result => {
      this.projects = result;
    },
    err => {
        // handle error in template through flag (need to setup flag)
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I fetch all the projects once but crud ops such as update or delete are both updated in the cache and on the server. So when an update to a project occurs it needs to update every component that is a subscriber to a particular observable which in this case I'm using behavior subject.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your service where  `this.projectService.getProjectsChange` is actually set or is a declared observable?

Comment: within the service as getProjectsChange = this.getProjectsSource.asObservable();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.  The biggest comes from this if:

```
if (this.projects != null){}
else {/* http request to get projects */}
```

Your `else` will never be triggered because `this.projects` is not `null`.  You set it to the empty array with

```
private projects: Project[] = [];
```

So you should set it to `null` instead, or not set it at all.

Comment: so within the map of the get request should I call 
            this.getProjectsSource.next(this.projects);

Comment: then have the components subscribe to the change, which will update every subscriber

Comment: @grimlek My solution doesn't use `getProjectsSource`; it's just what I have up there.  The component subscribes to the observable returned by `getProjects()`

Comment: right but if another component updates data then that change isn't pushed to the other components which need updating, so i end up with stale data that needs to be rerendered/updated

Comment: So data isn't fetched just once from the server? The components can add to the `projects` array?

Comment: no its not, I fetch all the projects once but crud ops such as update or delete are both updated in the cache and on the server. So when an update to a project occurs it needs to update every component that is a subscriber to a particular observable which in this case im using behavior subject.

Comment: I see. Then it makes sense to have a `BehaviorSubject` class property, and allow components to `.next()` values into it and/or subscribe to it as they see fit. I better understand what you were doing.

Comment: @grimlek I'll remove that part of my answer. It's the first part that fixes your problem anyway.